# UITableView Header section height is not adjusted automatically for a Custom UIView() class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uitableviewsectionheader

I am having UIView() class where I am adding a label programatically and also given constraints to automatically adjust height of view based on content. I have used this class as HeaderView for a UItableView section. But the problem here is the height of this view is not adjusting accordingly to its content.

Here he is my code of that custom View.

```
class DynamicHeaderView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let headerLabel = UILabel()
    headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    headerLabel.text = "This is header view. It is dynamicaaly growing text and will automaticaly get adjusted to it"
    self.backgroundColor = .green
    headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(headerLabel)

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -16))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

    self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -10))
} }
```

Code that I have written in my viewController,

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.countriesTable.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension;
    self.countriesTable.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 25 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = DynamicHeaderView()
    return headerView
}
```

The height is always stick to the estimated header height as 25 which i have given in viewDidLoad() function.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have a bottom constraint. Therefore auto-layout doesn't know how to automatically size your header view. The answer below includes that missing constraint.

Comment: @DoesData... Missed that line to add that here from my code But now I have updated. So no issue in my code it seems.

Comment: you should remove that line so that the question makes sense to anyone who comes here.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to remove that line from here. Because this is my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` , then register the tableView with it , finally implement `viewForHeaderInSection`

```
class DynamicHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    let headerLabel = UILabel()

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
     //   headerLabel.sizeToFit()
        headerLabel.text = "This is header view. It is dynamicaaly growing text and will automaticaly get adjusted to it"
        self.backgroundColor = .green
        headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(headerLabel)

        headerLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000), for: .vertical)

        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 16))

        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -16))

        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

        self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerLabel, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

//

In `viewDidLoad`

```
 tableView.register(DynamicHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "celld")  

 tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 50 

 tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "celld") as! DynamicHeaderView


    headerView.headerLabel.text = "heightForHeaderInSectionheightForHeaderInSectionheightForHeaderInSectionheightForHeaderInSectionheightForHeaderInSectionheightForHeaderInSection"

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: This is not solution to my problem. I want to keep everything in Custom Header view class and you are saying to calculate height manually in heightForHeaderInSection. Then whats the use of having automatic section header height option.